# WPF: access ElementName in a list within a list on the XAML side

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm having a hard time solving a potential newbie problem: I've got a `ObservableCollection<TopItem> MyTopItems` that I display in a `ListView`. The type `TopItem` contains a string `TopName` and an `ObservableCollection<NestedItem> NestedItems`. The type `NestedItem` contains only a string `NestedName`.
My problematic is quite simple: I want to retrieve information on the nested item that I select, on the XAML side.
Right now, I can retrieve the selected item of `TopItems` quite easily, but I can't retrieve the selected item of `NestedItems`.
I know that I can bind the selected item (for `TopItems` and `NestedItems`) in the view model, but in my case it's almost pointless because I've got no use for it in the view model. Plus, I'd really like to know how to do it on the XAML side!
Enough talk, now comes the code.

A class to implement to `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface that I'm gonna use in my models and view model; not the cleanest way of doing, but it's for the sake of the demo. This class is just there to see the big picture, just know that it works well:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.Utils
{
    public abstract class INPCBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisedPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(storage, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                storage = value;
                RaisedPropertyChanged(propertyName);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comes the `NestedItem` type:

```cs
using WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.Utils;

namespace WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.Model
{
    public class NestedItem : INPCBase
    {
        private string _NestedName;
        public string NestedName
        {
            get { return this._NestedName; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref this._NestedName, value);
            }
        }

        public NestedItem(string nestedName)
        {
            NestedName = nestedName;
        }
    }
}
```

The `TopItem` type:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.Utils;

namespace WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.Model
{
    public class TopItem : INPCBase
    {
        private string _TopName;
        public string TopName
        {
            get { return this._TopName; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref this._TopName, value);
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<NestedItem> _NestedItems;
        public ObservableCollection<NestedItem> NestedItems
        {
            get { return this._NestedItems; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref this._NestedItems, value);
            }
        }

        public TopItem(string topName)
        {
            TopName = topName;
        }
    }
}
```

The view model:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.Model;
using WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.Utils;

namespace WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.ViewModel
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INPCBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TopItem> _TopItems;
        public ObservableCollection<TopItem> TopItems
        {
            get { return this._TopItems; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref this._TopItems, value);
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            TopItems = new ObservableCollection<TopItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var topItem = new TopItem($"top item {i}")
                {
                    NestedItems = new ObservableCollection<NestedItem>()
                };

                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    var nestedItem = new NestedItem($"NI {j}");

                    topItem.NestedItems.Add(nestedItem);
                }

                TopItems.Add(topItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the most important part: the XAML!:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfSelectItemInDoubleList"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfSelectItemInDoubleList.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="List in list" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="TopItemsLV" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding TopItems, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TopNameTB" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TopName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <ListView x:Name="NestedItemsLV" ItemsSource="{Binding NestedItems}" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SelectionMode="Single">
                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NestedName}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ContentControl Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=TopItemsLV, Path=SelectedItem.TopName}" />
        <ContentControl Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding ElementName=NestedItemsLV, Path=SelectedItem.NestedName}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The interesting part is the second `ContentControl`. The first one is working well, but the second doesn't: nothing is showing when I select a nested item. A hint is given to me by intellisense: it sees the `TopItemsLV`, but not the `NestedItemsLV`.
Prepare for the most beautiful UI ever. Please don't stole it from me, I'm planning to make millions out of it! Just kidding.

[image: Best UI ever]
As you can see, the selected item from `TopItems` is showing, but not the selected item from `NestedItems`. Any idea why?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Skip the first solution.  It's more appropriate for *really* simple views.  Scroll down to my second solution instead.

If you are only binding a single `ItemsControl` (e.g., `ListView`) to this list of `TopItem` instances, then you could just the default collection view manage the selected items for you.  That's probably the *simplest* way to do this.

First, set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on both `TopItemsLV` and `NestedItemsLV`.

Then, change your content control bindings as follows:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=TopItems/TopName}" />
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=TopItems/NestedItems/NestedName}" />
```

The `/` separator in a binding path means "drill down into the currently selected item".  The selected item is maintained by the default collection view for both your `TopItems` collection and each `NestedItems` collection.  The default collection view is what you would get if you called `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`.

---

#### Better Solution

The conventional MVVM approach would be to add a `SelectedItem` property alongside your `TopItems` and `NestedItems` collections.  Make sure they fire property change events.  The property type should match the corresponding collection's element type.  If these properties start out with a null value, then nothing will be selected initially, which is what you want.

On both list views, set `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"`.  Remove the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` settings from my original answer.

Adjust your content control bindings as follows:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.TopName}" />
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.SelectedItem.NestedName}" />
```

Attach a new event handler to `NestedItemsLV`:

```
<ListView x:Name="NestedItemsLV"
          GotFocus="OnNestedItemsLVGotFocus"
          ... />
```

In your view's code-behind, implement the handler as follows:

```
private void OnNestedItemsLVGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
    var parentItem = (sender as FrameworkElement)?.DataContext as TopItem;

    if (viewModel != null && parentItem != null)
        viewModel.SelectedItem = parentItem;
}
```

I think you'll agree that this solution works better.

Comment: It's a good point! Now, I have got something that appears for the selected nested item. Nonetheless, it brings 2 problems: first, the first item of `TopItems` and first item of each `NestedItems` are selected -> their name show in the UI. By default, I want all of them to be unselected. Next, if I select "directly" a nested item (meaning not clicking a top item then a nested item), the UI doesn't update: with this approach, I need to select a top item _and_ a nested item. I'm starting to wonder if it's possible in XAML after all. Your second solution might be the only valid in that case.

Comment: I'm going to suggest you forget my original solution.  Your requirements are a bit too nuanced for relying on collection views.  I added a better solution to my answer, and this one is more conventional as far as following MVVM patterns.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Your second solution seems correct. Too bad that XAML can't do what I wanted: avoid to create the `SelectedItem` in my models. Not a big deal, but I though it could be "simply" possible :) I'll test that as soon as I can and mark it as the answer.

Comment: If you don't want to track selection in your _item_ models, you could declare `SelectedNestedItem` in your _view_ model, and `null` it out whenever `Selected[Top]Item` changes.  But it wouldn't remember the nested item selection for previously selected top items unless you keep an explicit history in your view model.  It's up to you to decide the best approach.